# Killing the robot in our Twitter account

Tags: discussion, twitter

Just wanted to let everyone know that we are testing out using <s>@StackGaming</s> [@TheArqade](https://twitter.com/#!/thearqade) manually. Until very recently, @TheArqade was only used to autotweet questions from our site, but we think that Twitter can be a really effective tool for engaging with the Stack Exchange Gaming community as well as other big gamers. If you decide you want to follow @TheArqade, you can expect to see more varied content, including

- Great questions and answers
- Blog posts from our site
- Contest announcements
- Industry news - such as game releases and posts from places like
  IGN, etc.

We will also make an effort to follow and highlight our users, as outlined in [this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4008/twitter-list-of-gaming-se-users). Along those same lines, interacting with @TheArqade on Twitter will be an easy way for people (users and non-users) to contact an employee of Stack Exchange.

Please be aware that this is an experiment to see whether investing resources in Twitter is a worthwhile way to grow the site. For now, only @TheArqade and @AskDifferent are being controlled manually. **This may or may not happen with other sites in the future, based on whether this experiment is successful**. Decisions about other sites' Twitter accounts will be made after this experiment is concluded. We don't have a date set for those decisions, or the end of this trial run.

Feedback on how the Twitters are being handled is welcome. Feel free to post comments, suggestions, etc. as answers here.

Comment: Why are you killing my family? T_T

Comment: I don't see any slot to enter my twitter handle when I try to edit my profile?

Answer (score 38):

<s>So long as you continue to post awesome question titles with no context for maximal confusion of Twitter followers, I fully endorse this product and/or service.</s>

As of 11/29/12, it looks like the Robot is back on, and tweeting odd meta posts with no context.

I guess the experiment was a failure?

Comment: +1 for [How can i tell if a corpse is safe to eat?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat) LOL

Comment: @Brandon This site is all about confusing question titles!

Comment: [What's the range of my ferret?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69540/whats-the-range-of-my-ferret/)

Comment: [I am currently on fire. Can I survive this?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61280/)

Comment: If I had to guess I'd bet they killed the idea due to the twitter account's low follower count. It's about in-line with most SE sites with rather low followership. In contrast UX has about 4x as many followers: https://twitter.com/StackUX Which, to my knowledge, is the highest of any individual site's twitter, beat out only by @stackexchange

Comment: I'm sure as heck not going to follow a robot.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not that it was a failure, but the people that were assigned to our SE are no longer employees or re-assigned to other tasks... it's a shame :(

Answer (score 5):

Lovin' it!

One minor point of feedback. If the bot tweeted a question it would show up in the history, see example screenshot for [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/posts/437250/revisions) below, which I found useful at times. This is not the case for the robot-replacement (see [this Twitter status](https://twitter.com/TheArqade/status/213664960264409088) vs [the revision history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/66391/revisions)).

If the experiment turns out to be a success it would be a *nice-to-have* to see tweets turn up in the revision history again.

Either way, keep up the great promotional work for <strike>Gaming</strike> Arqade SE!

**Example**:
[image: Tweeted example]